# Laravel upload file in database and store it as well in public folder

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-storage

Can someone help me while enrollment_form gets uploaded to the database? I also want it to be uploaded/stored in the /public folder.

```
public function submitForm(Request $request)
{
    DB::table('enrollment')->insert([
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'enrollment_form' => $request->enrollment_form,
        'name' => $request->user_name,
        'email' => $request->user_email,
        'status' => $request->user_status
    ]);
    
    return back()->with('user_form', 'Enrollment successfully submitted!');
}
```

Comment: `laravel-8` or `laravel-9`? The manual has a page on [File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads)

Comment: @brombeer do u know what approach of insert function, i want only the first entry keep replacing each time i inserted value to the database?